# Can I recreate a corrupted RPM database?

Tags: rpm

I've experienced corrupt RPM DB. I know the RPM DB has information of packages installed on my system, but I'd like to know:

- How to rebuild it
- What happens when it's being rebuilt
- Consequences of messing with the RPM DB

After all, it's "just" keeping track of packages installed, versions etc. Right?

Comment: Yes, it's "just" the central database on which all your system software management is based. So, um, your third question is a bit open-ended but it says "software maintenance becomes impossible or incorrect".

Comment: Where can I find information to deep dive into it?

Comment: hm, what is there to dive into? *100%* of the functionality of `yum`/`dnf` depends on rpmdb, *everything* that the `rpm` program does that's not just concerned with looking inside a specific .rpm file that you have in front of you does. I presume you know how to use an RPM-based distro – so, all the things that have *anything* to do with installing, uninstalling, updating, getting infos about packages, or vice versa, about files installed *through* packages cease to function with a dysfunctional rpmdb. You're basically asking "If my motor is broken, which functionality of my car is affected?".

Comment: You need to dig up into the rpm source code to know about the exact internals, only the user-facing bits are documented.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I just want to get more information about it. E.g if you want to know how transistors works in depth, there's books for it, right?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the level of depth you want to go here; so far my impression was that you're very superficially asking what would stop to work, and how to use it, @N.J. my apologies if that was a misinterpretation! So as Christian Rodriguez says, if you want to look at the rpmdb implementation, you'll have to look at the source code. I don't think there's a book that strives to describe that - in the end, the implementation of a package database isn't *that* consequential that many people will sit down and write a book on it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

In case of:

```
    error: rpmdb: damaged header #5904 retrieved -- skipping.
```

Try:

```
    mkdir /var/lib/rpm/old/
    mv /var/lib/rpm/__db* /var/lib/rpm/old/
    rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
    restorecon -Rv /var/lib/rpm     # reset the SELinux security context for /var/lib/rpm/ directory to its default values
    rpmdb --rebuilddb -v
```